# MAX() Message Inbox Summary?

Tags: mysql, messagebox

This question has been asked 1000 times, but I can't get it to work by modifying other peoples examples.

I have a messages table:
  id
  message
  reciever_id
  reciever_seen
  sender_id

I want to create a mysql query that will show only the latest message sent for each conversation.

There can only be 1 conversation from user to user, and conversations cannot be deleted (for now)

The best answer will go to the responder who explains in detail how the query functions work together to give the results.

Comment: Introduce another entity `conversation` that would hold a reference to the latest message (and any additional data you need, like - the conversation beginning time, the conversation last message time, etc). So the best answer would be how to design your schema properly, not how to write a terribly performing query.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: @zerkms So you suggest a conversation table, is that really more efficient than a single query?

Comment: @RecoJohnson: could you imagine that "single query"'s execution plan? Could you imagine a query from `conversation` table?

Comment: And just for the record: yes, I do think that `conversation` table maintenance cost is **much** lower than performing a query you asked about. Btw, query is not complicated at all. 1. Write a query that would fetch the `MAX(id)` for every `source-destination` pair 2. wrap it in a nested query 3. Join it with a select from the same table 4. PROFIT!!11

Comment: i before e except after c